# PHP PDO Error Message as a Variable to send in email

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo, error-reporting

Making the switch to PDO from MySQL in PHP.  In the past, when a query was ran and wasn't executed for whatever reason, I was able to send myself an email with the mysql_error() message in the body like so:

```
$query = "SELECT dogs FROM animals";
$res = mysql_query($query);

if (!$res) {
    $error = "Error Message: " . mysql_error();
    mail("my@email.com","Database Error",$error);
}
```

From that I would be alerted by an emil when something was wrong with the database on a website.

My PDO setup is as follows:

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

I have a try catch in the PDO connection itself but I would like to get error messages for prepare and execute as they happen like so:

```
$query = "SELECT cats FROM animals";
$sql = $pdo->prepare($query);

if (!$sql->execute()) {
  $error = "Error Message: " . (pdo error message here);
  mail("my@email.com","Database Error",$error);
}
```

Any ideas on how to assign PDO error messages in an email subject? I'm able to get a logical error message if a prepare fails be using errorInfo() but on execute errors(such as invalid parameter counts for arrays), I can't seem to get an error message.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use try/catch

```
try {
    $sql->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage(); // This function returns the error message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply zjd.  Yes, I've tried that as well like so:

try {
    $sql->execute($pdo_data);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    mail("me@mail.com","Database Error",$error);
}

but I get this PHP error: CFatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object and the whole script stops.  It doesn't output anything in the catch block.

Comment: The error you're getting is because `$sql` doesn't have the function `execute()` associated with it. Are you sure you still have `$sql = $pdo->prepare($query);` in your script? If so, where do you initialize `$pdo`. Also, you can wrap code in "`" symbols and it will display better in these comments.

Comment: I did.  Now it's working because I changed ERRMODE_WARNING to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in my setAttribute().  After changing that, it did the trick.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$query = "SELECT cats FROM animals";
$sql = $pdo->prepare($query);

if (!$sql->execute()) {
  $arr = $sql->errorInfo();
  $error = print_r($arr, true);

  mail("my@email.com","Database Error",$error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay Carlos.  I did try that, but I just get this:


Array
(
   [0] => HY093
   [1] => 
   [2] => 
)

No real explanation to what the issue is.

Comment: You surely have an improperly binded variable. Are you sure `$query = "SELECT cats FROM animals";` is the SQL you're trying to execute ? if you're in fact binding some variable with :variable you need to take notice of bindParam and bindValue, which are a bit different. To start, just use bindValue which will accept anything you throw at it.

Comment: I'm well aware of binding.  I wrote a simple query just to get the message accross.  I wanted to get an error if the column cats didn't exist in animals.